# Discord bot cant give roles to users if server has 2fa requirements

Tags: discord, discord.js

So when i turn off server 2fa requirements my bot can successfully give roles to users but it cant give role to users if i turn on 2fa requirements of server on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a server your bot is in has the "2FA Requirement For Moderation" enabled, and you - the bot owner - do **not** have 2FA enabled on your account, your bot **won't** be able to carry out administrative actions on said server.
If you develop a bot within a team, all team members will need to have 2FA enabled on their account.

Enable 2FA on your account.